# Outlook HTML email - vertical gaps in image slices

Tags: html, email, outlook, slice

So, typical question. I have searched a boatload here. Tried everything suggested. Nutin'

So Maybe to ask the question fresh.

I am having some verical gaps in Outlook 2013 (and 2007 too i think) between my image slices. (Also my text  is extending further than it is set as)

Knowing that display:block doesn't really work for Outlook. I've tried wrapping in spans and giving the span a display:block

I'm at a loss. I'm hoping someone can answer this one easily. Grrrrr!!!! Outlook! Why must you be so popular?

http://pastebin.com/ESfEmWer
http://tinypic.com/r/2gtdhu1/6

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. I tried using display:inline-block made sure border-collapse:collapse; was property set and even took out ALL whitespace to be sure http://pastebin.com/aeTBi9kw  still get those gaps seen in the image http://tinypic.com/r/2gtdhu1/6  it's a head scratcher. I left in the display: because they are what helps Gmail from making horizontal gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Don't go for

```
display: [anything]
```

if you wish to include Outlook 2007. See http://www.xequte.com/support/maillistking/css_in_emails.html for reference of which CSS styles you can use and which you better don't.

Don't use any whitespaces trailing

```
<td>
```

and don't use any whitespaces preceding

```
</td>
```

And you should also avoid

```
<style>...</style>
```

as this will most likely will be striped away completely. Always go for inline-styles. And I know that this is not part of a real answer, but just as a hint: If you are doing HTML newsletters make them as if you were doing them for Internet Explorer 4. E-Mail clients like Outlook use the most ridiculous CSS-renderer you can imagine. Even Internet Explorer 5 is more sophisticated in rendering CSS then modern Outlooks.

Oh, and by the way: If there is a chance that the recipients of your newsletter might read them online in hotmail, gmx or gmail then you should check them, too. You will stand in awe and wonder how those online clients handle your code and what they inject.

Answer (score 1):

You have a ton of whitespace causing the gap:

```
<a href="mms://a1783.v167326.c16732.g.vm.akamaistream.net/7/1783/16732/0/QPS.Onstreammedia.com/origin/jjready2/%5bInbox%5d/Talent%20Management/CDF%201-18_WMV.wmv">
                            <img style="display:block" src="http://emaniocreative.com/eblasts/3_26_2013/Message-from-Dominic-&-Louise.jpg"  width="360" height="257" border="0" alt="Message from Dominic &#38; Louise - Video"></a>
```

Try taking the whitespace out.. also `display:block` doesn't work like `display:inline-block` (the later you probably want instead) You cannot add formatting such as `margin` or `padding` to `SPAN`. I would keep what you have as `IMG` and `DIV` elements, however if you are using a `TABLE` you may want the `border-collapse:collapse;` property set.

Also to note, if you are using `display:inline-block` you will want to take out *ALL* whitespace between your elements:

```
<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>
```

Instead of what you have currently:

```
<tr>
  ...
</tr>
<tr>
  ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have way too many colspans, which could cause problems. You should be nesting your tables instead.

I've created hundreds of emails and never had any issues with whitespace caused by line-returns in email code. (Outlook 2007 is the first thing I check my emails in)

It is always good practice to use `display:block;` and also keep images in their own `<td>` by themselves.

Try something like this instead:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ambassador Newsletter</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style>img {display:block}</style>
</head>

<!--REPLACE the following text with the path to the images on your server http://emaniocreative.com/eblasts/3_26_2013/ -->

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table bgcolor="#ebebeb" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;">
<table id="Table_01" width="650" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td>

<!-- NEST A TABLE INSTEAD-->
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#770000">
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:20px;">
            header
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
<!-- /NEST-->

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

<!-- NEST A TABLE INSTEAD-->
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:20px;">
            Body section 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:20px;">
            Body section 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
<!-- /NEST-->

        </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

In my example I used padding instead of cells for spacing.

**You never need a blank spacer image.** Use a `&nbsp;` in an empty cell instead if you prefer not to use padding:

```
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#770000">
    <tr>
      <td height="20" colspan="3">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td width="610">
        header
      </td>
      <td width="20">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20" colspan="3">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

On a side note, there is an unavoidable issue with vertical separation when forwarding from Outlook to Gmail for example, (courtesy of mso.normal p tags added) but for the initial recipient there are no problems.